# Counterexample to Inverse Operator Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $Y=(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}},\|\cdot\|_1)$ where $\|x\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|$, and $X=(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}},\|\cdot\|_X)$ where $\|x\|_X=\|x\|_1+\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n|x_n|$.
Then $\|\cdot\|_X$ is a norm since $\|ax\|_X=|a|\|x\|_X$ for a scalar $a$, $\|x\|_X=0$ implies $x=0$, and
\begin{align}
\|x_1+x_2\|_X&=\|x_1+x_2\|_1+\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n|x_{1n}+x_{2n}| \\
&\leq\|x_1\|_1+\|x_2\|_1+\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n|x_{1n}|+\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n|x_{2n}| \\
&=\|x_1\|_X+\|x_2\|_X.
\end{align}
Note that $\|x\|_1<\infty$ if and only if $\|x\|_X<\infty$ and that $\|x\|_1\leq\|x\|_X$.
Let $T:X\to Y$ be identity, which is continuous, linear, and bijective.
Then, $T^{-1}$ exists and is linear, but is not continuous.

Which assumption of the inverse operator theorem is violated in this example?

Comment: can you give a reference to the theorem you have in mind?

Comment: What exactly is your space? Is it finite dimensional or infinite dimensional? Your norm doesn't even exist in $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: You have to say what $X$ and $Y$ are, as sets. The question does no make sense in its present form.

Comment: I am referring to the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is not onto. The condition on $X$ is stricter than $Y$. Note the sequence given by $x_n=\frac{1}{k^2}$ if $n=k!$ and $x_n=0$ otherwise is in $Y$ but not in $X$.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to know.